# How to round a number in PHP

Tags: php, rounding

I run a wooocommerce site, weight is on Pounds, I need to convert them into Kilograms.

I've downloaded this script from a website, it does the job but it sets the new weight with a lot of decimals, not sure how to round it.

I was trying to use `round($new_weight, 2);` but it is not taking it or not sure where to place it or how.

**NOTE:** I do not know nothing about php. This script is a page template. It does the change when you open it.

```php
<?php
/*
 *
 * Template name: wconvertor
 */
get_header();

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 2500  );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
global $product; 

$weight= get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_weight', true);

if ( ! empty( $weight ) ) {

    echo "id = ".get_the_ID(). " weight = ".$weight; 

    $new_weight = $weight / 2.2 ; 
    round($new_weight,2);

    echo "<br>new weight = ".$new_weight."  ********************";

    // id , key , value 
    $result = update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_weight', $new_weight);
    echo "result = ".$result;

}else{
    echo "<br>NO update for: ".get_the_ID();
}
endwhile; 
wp_reset_query(); 
?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read this refrence:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

**Example:**

```
<?php
 echo round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96
 echo round(5.045, 2);    // 5.05
 echo round(5.055, 2);    // 5.06
?>
```

Edit your code to:

```
$new_weight = $weight / 2.2 ; 
$new_weight = round($new_weight,2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the value to some variable as

```
$new_weight = round($new_weight,2);
echo $new_weight;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_weight = float($weight) / 2.2 ; 
$new_weight = round($new_weight,2);
echo $new_weight;
```

try this